# Is it possible to apply treatement to all elements in XML jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I need to apply some treatment (such as double space removal )in all the elements in the XML file. I am using moxy implementation of jaxb. Is it possible to implement the same in jaxb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `CollapsedStringAdapter` to clean up your strings (or create your own).  If you want it applied to all `String` field/properties within a package you can specify this `XmlAdapter` using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` at the package level.

**package-info**

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=CollapsedStringAdapter.class, type=String.class)
package forum17484029;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17484029/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo>  A  B  C  </foo>
    <bar>   X   Y   Z   </bar>
</root>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo>A B C</foo>
    <bar>X Y Z</bar>
</root>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html